# How to Get only Change (Pts) column data (with minus values) from this Table in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, html-lists

[image][image]

I am trying with this XPath expression. It will fetch data (with - values) but for both column. But I want to fetch only change (Pts) column data.

```
//*[@id="div_bseindices"]/div/div/div/ul/li[contains(@class,'alignR red')]
```

Comment: Edit the question and share the HTML in the form of text rather than image. Also, share the URL of the application(if it's public).

Answer (score 0):

use the tag it will take the value which is in minus points
here I am using xpath which contains text as '-' hope it works
//*[@id="div_bseindices"]/div/div/div/ul/li[contains(text(),'-')]

Comment: Its working fine for both column Changes (Pts) and % Change. but i need to fetch only Change (Pts) column - value data.